# Insert textarea to selected option with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my database named `api` I have three columns `id`, `name` and `article`. I made a modal with a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Add</h5>
   </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Choose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <select class="form-control" name="select_c">
                  <?php
                     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        unset($id, $name);
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                     }
                  ?>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Article</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="article_c" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is my `add.php` which is included earlier in the code I copied above.

```
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "trying";

   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if (!$conn) {
      die("Could not establish connection." . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

      $article = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['article']);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO api (article) VALUES ('$article')";
      if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
         #echo "Records added successfully.";
      } else{
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }
   }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM api";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   mysqli_close($conn);
```

What I want to accomplish is when I have selected a `<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>`, the text I type in the `<textarea class="form-control" name="article_c" rows="4"></textarea>` will be inserted to the column `article` for that row I selected when I click submit.

How can I do this?

Comment: 1. Need `submit button` to submit your form.2. try to use `prepared statement` to prevent your code from `SQL Injection`. 3. you have  two `name` attribute in your form `select_c,article_c`, in which you din't use first-one in your php code at all and second-one is wrongly spelled in your php code. So i am afraid that your php code is not working at all.4. You have to tell use which column going to represent `select box selected value` at the time of `INSERT`

Comment: First of all, you need a SUBMIT button to post your form.

Comment: So there is id and name are already there and the article will be changed every time right?

Comment: @Prateik thats right. Name and ID already exists. My goal with this is to give "name" in this manner a description/article. Thats why I wanted the select form, because I wont be covering all of them.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I'm aware, I kinda left out some code because i didnt find it necessary to post the entire modal that contains mostly html. Updated where you can find submit tho. Thanks

Comment: it a whole code or i can say that its a whole operation everything is done by your side, now say what issue what error are you facing?

Comment: your php code and modal both are in same file or diffrent?

Comment: Different, @Rits. modal is in index.php, while add is "include 'add.php';" in top of index.php

Comment: then you have to define action in the form

Comment: action to the php file,